# Android ActionBar preferences text is black after Update to appcompat-v7:22.2.1'

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

I've updated my appcompat dependencies in Android Studio -> build.gradle from

> com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'

to

> com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'

After the update, the text of the title is black instead of white, but only in the Preferences. I'm using this toolbar.xml to style my ActionBar in the PreferencesActivity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</LinearLayout>
```

I've tried in vain to set the color in the xml file:

```
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
```

And I've tried to style the ActionBar in the style.xml, but without any success:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyTitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTitleTextStyle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

Does somebody has any idea?

Comment: If you use Toolbar as actionBar, you should use theme `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` as base

Comment: But I'm using the Toolbar only in the preferences

Answer (score 0):

You should set:

```
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
```

Comment: Sorry, but it has no effect to the Toolbar

Comment: I suggest you used this sample github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare

Comment: I don't want to use a new library or something else. That has to be solved in another way